# Impossible implicit move operations?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, move-semantics, compiler-bug

As far as I understand [[class.copy.ctor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor) and [[class.copy.assign]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign), struct `A` in the following code should not be move-constructible nor move-assignable:

```
#include <type_traits>


struct X {
  X() noexcept; // user-declared default constructor
  ~X() noexcept; // Force X not to be trivially copyable
  X(X &&) = delete; // Explicitly deleted move constructor
  X(X const &) = delete; // Explicitly deleted copy constructor
  X & operator=(X &&) = delete; // Explicitly deleted move assignment operator
  X & operator=(X const &) = delete; // Explicitly deleted copy assignment op.
};
static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible<X>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_copy_assignable<X>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_move_assignable<X>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_move_constructible<X>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_copyable<X>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_copy_assignable<X>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<X>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_move_assignable<X>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_move_constructible<X>::value, "");


struct A {
  A() noexcept; // user-declared default constructor
  A(A const &) noexcept; // user-declared copy constructor
  A & operator=(A const &) noexcept; // user-declared copy assignment operator
  X x;
};
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<A>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable<A>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_move_assignable<A>::value, "");        // FAILS?!
static_assert(!std::is_move_constructible<A>::value, "");     // FAILS?!
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_copyable<A>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_copy_assignable<A>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<A>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_move_assignable<A>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_move_constructible<A>::value, "");
```

However, two of the static assertions fail with both GCC and Clang, which mean that for some reason `A` is move-assignable and move-constructible.

In my reasoning this shouldn't be, because `struct A`:

- does not explicitly declare a move constructor
- does not explicitly declare a move assignment operator
- has a user-declared copy constructor
- has a user-declared copy assignment operator.
- has a field `x` of type `X` which is can not be direct-initialized with any other `A::x`, because all constructors of `X` which would participate in overload resolution for this are explicitly deleted.

Is this a compiler bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're expected behaviors, because the existence of copy constructor and copy assignment operator satisfies the requirement of [MoveConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible)

> A class does not have to implement a move constructor to satisfy this type requirement: a copy constructor that takes a const T& argument can bind rvalue expressions.

and [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable).

> The type does not have to implement move assignment operator in order to satisfy this type requirement: a copy assignment operator that takes its parameter by value or as a const Type&, will bind to rvalue argument.

Note that [std::is_move_constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible) and [std::is_move_assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_assignable) are just checking an object of the specified type can be constructed/assigned from an rvalue argument. Even there're no move constructor/assignment operator, copy constructor/assignment operator could do the work, because an rvalue argument could be passed to an lvalue reference to const too.

**EDIT**

Note for the sample code you showed the move constructor/assignment operator are not implcitly declared at all (because of the existence of user-declared copy constructor and copy assignment operator), so they won't affect overload resolution and the result that copy constructor/assignment operator would be invoked. But if you explicitly declared them as `delete`, behavior will change because explicitly deleted functions participate into overload resolution, and they will be selected preferentially, and then `std::is_move_constructible` and `std::is_move_assignable` will return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

`is_move_constructible/assignable` does not check if there is move constructor or move assignment operator. It check if class can be constructed/assigned from r-value reference. Classes lacking move faciities would just use copy constructor/assignment operator in this case.

Generally `is_move_constructible/assignable` is weaker than `is_copy_constructible/assignable`: later fails on move-only types, when former passes check.

Comment: @jotik you did not deleted them from `A`. Deleted and not generated are different things: deleted functions/constructors participate in overload resolution, not generated functions do not. Also `x` member is default initialized everywhere, as you did not tell it to otherwise in user-defined constructors.